# Thumbnail image doesn't show up in Shortcode output

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, shortcode, thumbnails, youtube

A '**WordPress Shortcode**' is being developed to display 'YouTube Channel Thumbnail' and 'Latest Playlist Thumbnail' when supplied with 'YouTube Channel ID' as follows.

`[yt_insert channel_id="UCbCmjCuTUZos6Inko4u57UQ"]`

[image]

**Shortcode implementation is as follows.**

```
function yt_insert_decode( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'channel_id' => ''
    ), $atts );

    $api_key = 'YOUTUBE_API_KEY';
    $channel_id = $atts['channel_id'];
    $api_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet,contentDetails&id=' 
    . urlencode($channel_id) . '&key=' . $api_key;

    $api_response = wp_remote_get($api_url);
    $api_response = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body($api_response) );

    $channel_thumbnail = $api_response->items[0]->snippet->thumbnails->default->url;
    $playlist_id = $api_response->items[0]->contentDetails->relatedPlaylists->uploads;

    $playlist_endpoint = 'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&id='
    . urlencode($playlist_id) . '&key=' . $api_key;

    $api_response = wp_remote_get($playlist_endpoint);
    $api_response = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body($api_response) );

    $playlist_thumbnail = $api_response->items[0]->snippet->thumbnails->default->url;

    $response = '<img src="' . $channel_thumbnail . '"> <img src="' . $playlist_thumbnail . '"> ';
    return $response;

}

add_shortcode( 'yt_insert', 'yt_insert_decode' );
```

'Channel Thumbnail' **DOES NOT** show up while 'Playlist Thumbnail' shows up.

[image]

How can I change the code so that 'YouTube Channel Thumbnail' shows up in my Shortcode output?

Comment: Have you done something like `var_dump( $api_response->items[0]->snippet->thumbnails->default->url ) );` to make sure the API is returning the data you expect it to?

Comment: And, correct me if I'm mistaken but, shortcodes should never echo anything. they should return the output.

Comment: @PatJ I have done and it returns a url (). But that doesn't show the image. (`"url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AKedOLS23dtcvEh1WXfWlV-fHTWUq6rvxR3FrQYmUDE11g=s88-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj-mo"`)

Comment: @uPrompt Yes it should return output. [Codex Link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API). I'll edit the question.

Comment: Perhaps check your browser's developer tools' Network tab and find the request for that image to see if there is a HTTP error which might provide additional insight.